# javascript how to define an inner function

Tags: javascript

I want to define an inner function within a function.

```
function outfunction(){
  function innerfunction(){
      alert('inner'); 
  }
  alert('out');
}
```

but the innerfunction is never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute it:

```
function outfunction(){
  function innerfunction(){
      alert('inner'); 
  }
  innerfunction();
  alert('out');
}
```

Or:

```
function outfunction(){
  (function(){
      alert('inner'); 
  })();
  alert('out');
}
```

Comment: It's not self-executing: the call operator (parenthesis) exist outside the function's definition.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the nested function:

```
function outfunction(){
    function innerfunction(){
        alert('inner'); 
    }
    alert('out');
    innerfunction(); // like this
}
```

The fact a function is nested only means it has a limited scope.

Comment: typo, `innerfunction()` rather than `innerFunction()` (case-sensitive)